# how to include all subdirectories as gradle modules?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm going to have a lot of submodules in my main project directory `x`, like `x/module1`, `x/module2`...

can i avoid manually adding every single module into `settings.gradle`? can i somehow script it to find all the subdirectories and add them automatically?

Comment: It's the Groovy programming language. You can script whatever you like (I.e. Recursively scanning a directory using Java `File` API)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *cricket_007* already mentioned, Gradle is based on the Groovy programming language (which is, like Java, executed in the JVM) and the `settings.gradle` file is nothing more but a Groovy script.

Whenever you use `include 'project'`, the `include` method of a [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) instance is called, so for your goal, you could simply create a loop which iterates over all folders and calls `include` for each of them.

A more 'groovyesque' approach would be the usage of a closure for each subdirectory, provided by the [Groovy SDK extension](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) for the `File` class:

```
file('.').eachDir { sub ->
    include sub.name
}
```

There are multiple ways to solve your problem, e.g. since the `include` method accepts an array of project path strings, you could also aggregate all required paths first and pass them all together. Simply get familiar with the Gradle docs and decide on your own, what solution suits your case the best.